# url rewrite issue by .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have issue on url rewrite i am want to change url

http://www.example.com/mbl.php?domain=example.com to  http://www.example.com/mbl/example.com

So i have written code myself by as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/mbl/([^/]+)$ /mbl.php?domain=$1
```

But its not working. so please to my error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try your rules this way and remove the leading slash from the rewriterule with `mbl` since you are using it in .htaccess file.

Give these rules a try.

```
#Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^mbl/([^/]+)$ /mbl.php?domain=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```